# Checking existence of file: URL stored in db VS checking file system

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I need to print images on ASP.NET site for each order.
Part of the images hosted on external server(cloud) and other part hosted on the same server.
There is a big folder of orders and each order has its own folder inside that big folder.
/Orders/Order_id/

When user load the page i have 2 options, to check if images exists and can be loaded: 
By saving in sql table url to each path of file, And if url exists then i can just call it.
-This will make my db tables to save huge amount of url strings.
Or, I can avoid saving anything in db, and every page load to go and check if files exist in folder.

What will be the fastest loading time and minimal resources(cpu and ram) consumption solution to use sql urls and save all that urls or each page load to check if files exist on folder?

Comment: Depending of how you set up indexes in the DB the DB could be faster because it is built for fast lookup. But if you still store the file on disk and not in the db you would also have to validate that the file exists in the location that the DB provided.
So if you do not store the image in the db I do not think the db is a worth while option. Also if the machine has a SSD I think the performance would be fast enough.
If you solution has a wide (geographical) footprint you can also investigate a CDN.

Comment: Files stored on Disk. Not in sql, in future files will be all stored on external host cloud 
 services, not on local server.

Comment: Probably also depends on how often they do exist. But the time to read a URL out of the database should be so miniscule that you don't have to worry about it.